# how to override date datatype to another region date datatype in SQL SERVER 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, date, calendar, sqldatatypes

I need to insert my date values on website application to it's sqlserver table, but in solar date format. The problem is, The first month until the sixth month, the days counts are 31 days, in ***solar*** calendar and when I insert for ex: **1394-02-31** 
,
[image]

sql server give me an error that

> [image]

, ***because february has not 31 days***.
So I try to add some new datatype that derived from date datatype as below fig:
[image]

but I'm confused when I want to fill values.

[image]

So, Please help me to solve my problem, **are there any sources to show me how to add new date datatype in sqlserver 2008?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948351/is-it-possible-to-change-the-datatype-date-in-sql-server

Same question was raised earlier, some good suggestions here but no absolute solutions.

Comment: In case you try to go with solution suggested in that question (pointed by Darshan): http://www.databaseskill.com/4316542/

Comment: Thanks @DarshanBI-DW , But they mean create function or somting like this. I want create new my own dataType not any converter function :(