# PersianCalendar can't convert year/month/31(day) to standard date

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format, persian, datetime-conversion

I am trying to convert `persianDate` to `standarddate` .

```
public DateTime ConvertPersianToEnglish(string persianDate)
{
    string[] formats = { "yyyy/MM/dd", "yyyy/M/d", "yyyy/MM/d", "yyyy/M/dd" };
    DateTime d1 = DateTime.ParseExact(persianDate, formats,
                                      CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
    PersianCalendar persian_date = new PersianCalendar();
    DateTime dt = persian_date.ToDateTime(d1.Year, d1.Month, d1.Day, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    return dt;
}
```

The `Persiandate` has formats like this: `1392/10/12(Year/month/day)`

In my application i am trying to convert `Year/month/31` to standard time but i got this error :

```
{System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
   at System.DateTimeParse.ParseExactMultiple(String s, String[] formats, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles style)
```

The exactly value that i get the error is `1393/04/31`

Comment: Does the month have 31 days in it?

Comment: If you  mean in persian yes it does.some months in persian has 31 days

Comment: But does the month you are trying to convert? "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime" valid is the key word here.

Comment: Yes the time that i try to convert is 1393/04/31> as i mentioned in my question

Comment: See this it should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655116/how-to-convert-persian-calendar-date-string-to-datetime

Comment: this one is useful too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9491805/704749

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sergey's solution of explicitly using a culture which uses the Persian calendar should work, but another option is to use my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) library:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using NodaTime;
using NodaTime.Text;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()        
    {
        // Providing the sample date to the pattern tells it which
        // calendar to use.

        // Noda Time 2.0 uses a property instead of a method.
        // var calendar = CalendarSystem.Persian;           // 2.0+
        var calendar = CalendarSystem.GetPersianCalendar(); // 1.x

        LocalDate sampleDate = new LocalDate(1392, 10, 12, calendar);
        var pattern = LocalDatePattern.Create(
            "yyyy/M/d", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, sampleDate);
        string text = "1393/04/31";
        ParseResult<LocalDate> parseResult = pattern.Parse(text);
        if (parseResult.Success)
        {
            LocalDate date = parseResult.Value;
            // Use the date
        }
    }    
}
```

Unlike `DateTime`, the `LocalDate` result here knows that it's just a date (so won't offer time aspects) and also knows which calendar system it's in (so you don't need to keep calling methods like `calendar.GetYear(date)` to get specific parts).

Note that a parse pattern of `yyyy/M/d` will be able to parse values with leading zeroes, so you don't need multiple patterns. If you know the format always *will* have two digits for the month and day, however, I'd explicitly use `yyyy/MM/dd` instead.

Answer (score 2):

## Explanation

There are couple of problems here:

1. ```
   DateTime d1 = DateTime.ParseExact(persianDate, formats,
                                     CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
   ```

   CultureInfo.CurrentCulture is machine dependent. But the function name is `ConvertPersianToEnglish` which means that `provider` argument of `ParseExact` should be set to Persian date format provider.
2. For some reason, Iranian CultureInfo instances has GregorianCalendar as a default calendars. Moreover, it doesn't have `PersianCalendar` in `OptionalCalendars`. Which is weird because `System.Globalization` namespace includes `PersianCalendar` class.

## Solutions

There are couple options that you can use here.

### Solution 1

In [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/250740/Fixing-Optional-Calendars-for-Persian-Culture-in-N) Babak Mahmoudi provides a helper class that can fix `CultureInfo` instance to accept `PersianCalendar`. Methods inside this class are not very gentle (in terms of implementation). But it contains `FixPersianDateTimeFormat` method which is quite innocent. Using it, your code would look like this:

```
public static DateTime ConvertPersianToEnglish(string persianDate)
{
    string[] formats = { "yyyy/MM/dd", "yyyy/M/d", "yyyy/MM/d", "yyyy/M/dd" };
    DateTimeFormatInfo persianDateTimeFormatInfo = new CultureInfo("fa-Ir").DateTimeFormat;
    PersianCultureHelper.FixPersianDateTimeFormat(persianDateTimeFormatInfo, true);
    return DateTime.ParseExact(persianDate, formats, persianDateTimeFormatInfo, DateTimeStyles.None);
}
```

### Solution 2

You can parse string yourself and then use `PersianCalendar.ToDateTime`. See comecme's answer here: [How to convert Persian Calendar date string to DateTime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655116)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way to convert Persian date to DateTime:

```
    public DateTime GetGregorianDate(string persianDate)
    {
        PersianCalendar persian_date = new PersianCalendar();
        var dateParts = GetDateParts(persianDate);
        DateTime dt = persian_date.ToDateTime(dateParts[0], dateParts[1], dateParts[2], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        return dt;
    }

    public int[] GetDateParts(string persianDate)
    {
        return persianDate.Split('/').Select(datePart => int.Parse(datePart)).ToArray();
    }
```