# Crashing the program on a specific date

Tags: c#

I use this code to get date

```
String.Format("{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", Convert.ToDateTime(calender.Text))
```

It work correct.

But I cannot get 3 special data so my program crashing.

in the day "31" and Month "2" , "4" , "6" for example `"1397/06/31"`or `"1397/04/31"`

How to fix it?
I use persian date calendar.

Comment: I imagine this gves you an errror as those are not valid dates. Months 2,4, and 5 does not have 31 days.

Comment: For persian date times please refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9491805/1300049

Answer (score 7):

Because there is no such thing as 31st of June, your conversion fails.

You should try parse it:

```
DateTime.TryParse("1900/06/31", out calendarDay)
```

And proceed only if conversion was successful (TryParse returns true)

Answer (score 5):

It will crash because `31st June`, `31st April` and `31st February` are not valid dates. Why do you want these dates to be as input?

Comment: my date is  Shamsi

Comment: Month "2" , "4" , "6"  is not june and april and february

Comment: 31st  ordibehesht  ,  31st tir  and   31st shahrivar

Comment: Shamsi as in Persian calendar?

Comment: Yes  Persian calendar